# Add arrays in one single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

what I'm trying to do is get arrays from my data and put them together in one single array, this is mine for the loop that give me my arrays.

```
citaArray = [];
for (var key in data) {
        var dataTest = data[key].cita;
        console.log(dataTest);
      }
```

This is the result of the console log of the array, how can they all in the citaArray??

```
["60669c353c16a2248c51bd2a", "606a74c28f8d950dcc77e4f8", "606e72ec3615341594a2b26d", "606f01075b501b295c1a9710", "606f9117cd77280afc4fa09e"]
["606a762bb2a4f50128df692c"]
["6049c2a5a1e5523e203c323a", "606e70c86284114e9897b343", "606e710ecc23bc2260773a64"]
```

Comment: javascript and java are not the same

Comment: try using `citaArray.push()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can concatenate them like this

```
citaArray = [];
for (var key in data) {
    var dataTest = data[key].cita;
    citaArray = citaArray.concat(dataTest);
}
```

you can see a live example here [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_concat)

Answer (score 1):

You can complete it by using `Spread ...` operator like this.

```
const citaArray = [];
for (var key in data) {
    citaArray = [...citaArray, ...data[key].cita]
}
```

Or using [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
const citaArray = data.flatMap(r => r.cita);
```

> The `flatMap()` method *returns a new array formed by applying a given
> callback function to each element of the array*, and then flattening
> the result by one level.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6 features, spread operator will be a best suitable tools for such operations

```
let citaArray = [];
for(let values of Object.values(data)){
    citaArray = [...citaArray, ...values]
}

console.log(citaArray)
```

Here is the jsfiddle with the sample data provided in question [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeldikk/9dyc74pa/3/)